# Is it unprofessional to inform/hand in my resignation to my level 2 manager instead of my immediate manager?

Tags: professionalism, resignation, manager

I'm more comfortable with my level 2 manager as he's more friendly and understanding than my immediate manager who's cold and serious most of the time. I'm afraid I'll get a huge blow back from my immediate manager for resigning after only 2 months in this multi-national company(due to emergency personal reasons).

Thus, i'm planning to hand in my resignation to my level 2 manager instead of my immediate manager. I was wondering is it professional to do so and whether I would be burning any bridges?

Comment: Generally, you submit your resignation to your direct manager. You're welcome to cc your manager's manager on your resignation. In my experience, it didn't really matter that much. I've resigned with my direct manager and my manager's manager too.

Comment: If your direct manager is on vacation, there's nothing unusual about it. Just add both as the main recipients of the resignation email. Your manager's manager will (should) know that your direct manager is on vacation.

Comment: @JuhaUntinen I don't think direct manager is on vacation or otherwise unavailable, OP is purposefully trying to avoid him in the process.

Answer (score 14):

Yes, usually it is the rule to "report" to your "reporting manager". Your comfort level does not change the "rule". You can also include your +2 manager (manager of your manager) in the communication, but that's optional. Skipping your immediate superior (disregarding your comfort level) is not only unethical but may also invalidate your notification altogether (based on organization policies).

In other words, your resignation notification should flow from you to your superior to theirs, not the other way around.

I believe you don't have a tool in place where you would submit the resignation (*I wonder why, given the organization description*), if that's the case, the preferred approach is to submit the resignation to your immediate supervisor, also known as "reporting manager".

Plan to have a **face to face meeting** for the submission of resignation - avoid having it only over e-mail / portal. E-mail / portal is for the official record-keeping.

---

Regarding the "anticipated" blow-back: Even if you take the skip-level route, your boss is going to know about the resignation eventually (if not immediately). I see no reason for him to be more pleasant towards you for keeping him/her in dark about your decision.

**Do your part, follow the protocols, and make a graceful exit.** You wont gain anything by trying to skip levels here.